# Powershell Get-Content with Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I have a file like this:

```
line one email1
line two email1
line three email2
line four email1
```

If I want to extract only the lines that contain "email1", I do this:

```
$text = Get-Content -Path $path | Where-Object { $_ -like *email1* }
```

$text is now an array with 3 elements containing those lines, and I iterate through it like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $text.Length; $i++)
{
#do stuff here
}
```

However, if I want to get the lines containing "email2".

```
$text = Get-Content -Path $path | Where-Object { $_ -like *email2* }
```

returns a string, rather than an array of one element.
And when I iterate through it, it iterates through each char in the string.

How can I make it an array with one element rather than a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked it out.

I need to declare $text as type `[String[]]`.

```
[String[]]$logText = Get-Content -Path $path | Where-Object { $_ -like *email1* }
```

Comment: Good one. See also "more generic" approach in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

In order to get an **array** always, even with 1 (i.e. not string) or 0 (i.e. not `$null`) items, use the operator `@()`:

```
$text = @(Get-Content -Path $path | Where-Object { $_ -like *email1* })
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of getting the `Length` method to treat a single element statement as an array, I think a better solution would be to use a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop to iterate:

```
foreach ($element in $text) {
    #stuff happens
}
```

will always parse through each element in `$text`, even if it's a single element.

Comment: my problem is that $text is sometimes a string, sometimes an array of String. Foreach on a string would just iterate through each char wouldn't it?

Comment: No - if you `foreach` a string the loop will only run once, since a string only contains a single element (the string itself). Character count has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

You also could use the `Select-String` Cmdlet, it worked for me even with only one result in the selection :

```
$text1 = Get-Content -Path $path | Select-String "email1"
$text1 | % { 
    # Do some stuff here
}

$text2 = Get-Content -Path $path | Select-String "email2"
$text2 | % { 
    # Do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: That's because `%` is an alias for `foreach` so you're really just relying on what @Kohlbrr said: `foreach` or `%` will work on a single string or an array.

Comment: @gruntzy thanks - found where using select string with a regex would return the object array I needed!